# No exporta las props de mi componente cuando tiene forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite, props

Tengo este codigo:

Estoy utilizando tailwind para algunas props dinamicas

```
const LabelClassProps = cva(["text-text-800"], {
variants: {
    size: {
        sm: "text-xs",
        md: "text-sm",
        lg: "text-md",
    },
  },
  defaultVariants: {
    size: "sm",
  },
});
```

Envuelvo las props en una sola

```
type LabelProps = ComponentProps<"label"> &
VariantProps<typeof LabelClassProps> &
IF_Label;

export const LabelFormComponet = forwardRef<HTMLLabelElement, LabelProps>(
(props, ref) => {
    const {
        id,
        required = false,
        size = "sm",
        error,
        touched,
        classNameContainer,
        className,
        label,
        startContent,
        endContent,
        disabled,
        ...rest
    } = props;

    const classLabel = twMerge(
        "flex justfy-between",
        clsx(
            required && "after:content-['*'] after:ml-1",
            disabled ? "after:text-text-800" : "after:text-danger-700",
            !disabled && error && touched && "text-danger-700"
        )
    );

    const classContainer = twMerge(
        "flex justify-between items-center w-full text-text-800 mb-2",
        clsx(!disabled && error && "text-danger-700"),
        classNameContainer
    );

    return (
        <div className={classContainer}>
            <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
                {startContent || null}

                <label
                    htmlFor={id}
                    ref={ref}
                    className={cn(
                        LabelClassProps({
                            size,
                            className,
                        }),
                        classLabel
                    )}
                    {...rest}
                >
                    {label}
                </label>
            </div>

            {endContent || null}
        </div>
    );
 }
 );
```

y cuando hago el npm run build me ejecuta esto, me sale solo la ref pero no las props y eso cuando lo pongo en otro proyecto no puedo acceder a ellos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio si le quito el forwardRef me sale esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo utilizo en otro proyecto mi componente si puedo acceder a las props.

¿Como puedo acceder a las props sin perder el **forwardRef**>?

Gracias por el apoyo.